# What is the proper way to close an Activity from a Service?

Tags: android

Can finish() be used to close an activity from a service?  If not, what is the proper way to end an activity from a Service?  I've created an activity from my service and need to close it.

Comment: Is this strictly required? Activities are garbage collected as needed by the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can finish() be used to close an activity from a service?

Not directly. The service really really really really should not have a reference to the activity on which to call `finish()`.

> I've created an activity from my service and need to close it.

Odds are, you should not be starting the activity from the service in the first place. Users will attack you with axes if they feel you are interrupting them unnecessarily.

> If not, what is the proper way to end an activity from a Service?

Preferably, let the user close the activity. Those users who do not attack you with axes for interrupting them by popping up the activity will attack you with clubs for interrupting them by getting rid of the activity while they are using it.

Beyond that, use a `Messenger` or something to send a message from the service to the activity, and let the activity handle that as desired in a `Handler`, which could include calling `finish()`.

Answer (score 0):

When possible I usually prefer the override option for closing activities:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
}
```

And in the main activity:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(logTag,"onDestroy");
}
```

How the activity can be started:

```
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    super.onStart(intent, startid);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  How would I call this from the Service?  I launched the Activity with an intent from the service.

Comment: Then it might depend - is it an intent for an activity in an external program?

Comment: It is still an activity within my package.  So to start it I used...   Intent sCan = new Intent(ActionService.this, EmptyProgram.class); and then startActivity(sCan);                                              Now I just need to end it, but I want to end it from the service.

Comment: Then a finish() or possibly destroy() should do the trick. The best would be if the activity would "know" when to finish and thus make a clean exit (handled by the GC as suggested).

Comment: As a plan B - have you tried making an intent for it that makes it understand that it needs to wrap up things? :)